# firebase pushing not working for 2 places

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to push some data to my firebase db and then take that unique key that gets generated and add it to a different reference in my firebase db. The first promise gets executed but my code never goes into the second block to do the second push.

```js
//First set some values to the experiences reference
var experienceRef = firebase.database().ref('experiences');
var eref = experienceRef.push(expData).then((snap) => {
  alert("set experience object");
});

//Once the above push is done, get the unique value and set it into the participant reference
var participantRef = firebase.database().ref('participants').child(zone_id).child('experiences');
participantRef.set(eref).then((snap) => {
  alert("set the zone reference");
});
```

Comment: why don't you put it inside the first response `.then()` and use `expData` instead of `.set(eref)`? how you getting the unique key?

Comment: figured it out, thanks for the input!